# Run Redux action only when two other actions were triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have specified two Redux actions called `FETCH_PROFILE` and `FETCH_CATEGORIES` that run independently on application startup.

Is it possible, i.e. using Redux Saga, to run third action `INITIALIZE_APP` but only when both of above have been triggered?

In this case I'd not rely on the state change directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just use the `all` effect.

```
yield all([
  take(FETCH_PROFILE),
  take(FETCH_CATEGORIES),
])
yield put({type: INITIALIZE_APP})
```

Comment: Thank you god!! *when you're stuck at something for several minutes, and a stackoverflow answer solves all the problems in the universe.*